# Plesk and domain hosted externally

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, hosting, plesk

I have two hosting accounts (Personal one and a work one). I am doing some testing and would like to create a subdomain of a work domain (manage.domain.com) and host it on my personal account. Currently, my personal host is through 1and1 and is dedicated while the work one is shared with GoDaddy.

Work

I have gone into go daddy and created the subdomain. I have also added DNS records such as A, AAAA AND NS (i did not record a CNAME). I have noticed that if is type manage.domain.com it is redirecting to my personal server. However, it is directing to the blank admin page of the root of the server (which is maintained using Plesk).

Personal

Using Plesk I added the website (domain.com) and created the subdomain (manage.domain.com). I have also updated the websites hosting access using Plesk and assigned it the default values of my personal account. Using Plesk I also set the subdomain to the particular location of the files I want to test. However, I cannot get my server to recognize the address and redirect it to the proper location.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
J

Comment: Just refreshed my browser and i am getting ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Comment: removed nameservers and reset them to godaddy to resolve error above

Answer (score 0):

You can just create:

- in personal account domain(not subdomain) manage.domain.com
- on domain.com add DNS record of type A, name "manage" and IP address of personal hosting:
  [image: plesk add dns record]

After that "manage.domain.com" will resolving to hosting of your personal account and can be accessed because such domain exists.

Comment: I realize i can create a subdomain of a domain i have. However, i want to show the testing to some of the individuals at work and i want to show them how it would appear subdomain and all

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

What i did above was correct expect do not change the name servers on the work DNS(godaddy).

1. Add the website to plesk - it will give you an error about not being able to control the DNS settings which you have already adjusted on the original server (godaddy)
2. Add a subdomain of the website.
3. *** Ensure the subdomain is pointed to the correct folder within your server
   Done